# Returning not working

Tags: c#, return

I dont understand why i cannot access `studentinformation` from the function `getstudentinformation`. Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    getstudentinformation();
    string firstname = studentinformation[0];
}

static Array getstudentinformation()
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter the student's first name: ");
    string firstname = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("enter the student's last name");
    string lastname = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("enter student's gender");
    string gender = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] studentinformation = { firstname, lastname, gender };
    return studentinformation;
}
```

Visual Studio does not recognise the array and when i try to build the code there is this error of not recognising *studentinformation*.

Comment: Your code works. It's not very pretty, but it compiles and returns array. What exact error message you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] studentInformation = getstudentinformation();
        string firstname = studentinformation[0];
    }
    static string[] getstudentinformation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter the student's first name: ");
        string firstname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("enter the student's last name");
        string lastname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("enter student's gender");
        string gender = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] studentinformation = { firstname, lastname, gender };
        return studentinformation;
    }
```

You were not assigning to any variable the result of `getstudentinformation` and since the variable that you are trying to access is declared in another scope, you cannot have access to it.

Comment: It would be nice if you explained to him the difference between an Array and a string[]

Comment: This code is not  worng. If you check your answer before you post it, you could see, it will compile.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin how is it not wrong, are you sure you compiled his code and not this answer? as the answerer said how can you access studentinformation, when its declared internally?

Comment: @MaksimSimkin the code did not work as expected. studentinformation does not exists in Main()

Comment: ok, call in Main is wrong, but the method itself not, you could cast string[] to Array, that doesn't have a lot sense, but it works.

Comment: what is the difference between Array and string[] @johnny5

Comment: @MaksimSimkin correct you're down vote, since this answer is not only valid, but the preferred usage of C#, unless you're using .net1.0 you shouldn't be using array

Comment: @NicoRiff i replaced my downvote with up, on every case, code you proposed is better, than from topic starter

Comment: @RohanGandhi Array is not typed you can return an object array with string and ints etc in there, while string[] you know your always getting a string

Comment: @MaksimSimkin, since you did so I upvote your answers because it is important to know that its also possible to do so

Comment: @RohanGandhi it is better to use the specific type of array that you need, rather than use a general one as johnny 5 stated. I also noted that you have some lacks on your code. Some tips: use CamelCasing. studentinformation array can be converted to an object itself as Student

Comment: @RohanGandhi dont forget. If it helped dont forget to mark as answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your method is ok, wrong is how do you use it.  Do it this way:

```
var firstname = getstudentinformation().GetValue(0);
```

But i advice not to use this Array class and do it for example the way as NicoRiff proposed, with:

```
static string[] getstudentinformation()
```

and usage in main:

```
var firstname = getstudentinformation()[0];
```

`Array` class you have used is the base class of every array (`string[]` too), so your string array is this `Array`, but not every `Array` is a string array, there for you could cast one direction, but non another, more about it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx